# Check if a property exists in array of objects without looping over it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects as such:

```
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}]
```

How do I check whether property 'id' exists in the array of objects without using any kind of looping statements? Once found return some string or anything for example.

Comment: How can you traverse an array and check each element without a loop?

Comment: Do you just mean something like `arr[0].hasOwnProperty('id');`?

Comment: Use Array.Reduce?

Comment: What do you mean by *"'id' exists in the array of objects"*? Do you want to know whether *any* object has such a property, or all objects? And why are you imposing this weird restriction?

Answer (score 2):

**In the general case, you can't**; some kind of looping construct is necessary. The loop may or may not be in your code, but it'll be there. For instance, even if you took the array and ran it through `JSON.stringify` and then tried to use a regex on the result, A) That would be a Bad Idea™ **:-)**, and B) There would still be looping (in `JSON.stringify`, probably in the regex handling as well). Moreover, the overhead would be much higher than just doing your own looping.

***If***, in your case, you know **in advance** that the objects all have the same set of properties, then you can just check the first one:

```
if ("id" in arr[0])
```

...but again, only if you know in advance they all have the same set of properties.

Stretching a point, `in` has to check the object and, if the property isn't found, its prototypes — which might include a loop. :-) (Of course, any property access may have to do that.) So you might prefer

```
if (arr[0].hasOwnProperty("id"))
```

...also in theory, that too could involve a loop through prototypes to find the `hasOwnProperty` method (in practice, on a modern engine, it won't).

Comment: `if("prop" in obj)` loops over the object properties

Comment: @mhodges - Probably not.  It probably uses a hash lookup in some sort of property index (though the details are internal to the JS implementaiton).

Comment: @mhodges: No, it doesn't. (Perhaps you're thinking of `for-in`?) It checks to see **if** the property exists. The mechanics of that operation are up to the implementation. (But I should probably use `hasOwnProperty` rather than `in` since it will have to "loop" through the object's prototypes. But then, any property lookup does that, too.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My point exactly. lol. I'm curious as to why a simple `arr[0]["id"]` wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @mhodges: What if the `id` is `0`? Or `""`? We'd need `arr[0].id !== undefined` -- but even that wouldn't work. We can't use `arr[0].id` to determine whether the property exists; after it, it could be `id:undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well really the only one that would be an issue is `id: undefined`, which I suppose is a fair point

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and check the stringified array.

```js
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}],
    json = JSON.stringify(arr);

console.log(/"id":3(,|\})/.test(json));
console.log(/"id":42(,|\})/.test(json));
```

Comment: There's still looping involved in both the stringify and in the regex.  You simply can't look through an array or a string without some piece of code somewhere using a loop.

Comment: even the check with an index involves looping.

Comment: Beat me by 33 seconds lol... IMO this is the only reasonable solution given the requirements

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to create a function that stringifies your array and then uses a regular expression to look for a specific ID value like so:

The regular expression `.test()` is (internally) iterating over the characters in the JSON string, so at a foundational level, what you are asking for is not possible.

```js
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}];

function idExistsInArray(array, id) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\"id\":" + id + "(,|})");
    return regex.test(JSON.stringify(array));
}

console.log(idExistsInArray(arr, 1));
console.log(idExistsInArray(arr, 3));
console.log(idExistsInArray(arr, 55));
```

Comment: There's still looping involved in both the stringify and in the regex. You simply can't look through an array or a string without some piece of code somewhere using a loop.

Comment: you get `true` on `"id":100` and looking only for `1`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Good catch, I missed that - fixed